# Use of temporary folder

Tags: wordpress

I am writing to see if you can help me, I am with a web, where the hosting establishes the following rules:

Deposit structure with site pages in `/htdocs` directory, where should be home page.

Physical path to the root of the site `/srv/www/web/htdocs/`. You must place home page or front page loading page of the site in this directory `htdocs/`.

The physical path to the temporary upload directory is `/srv/www/web/tmp/`, which you must set in the configuration of each web application or technology you host in the same virtual hosting space. This temporary directory has enabled the necessary permissions for the correct functioning of the web applications that you host in your contracted virtual space.

Until now I had never encountered these restrictions. The issue is that when installing WordPress and logging in, the dashboard does not show any option for the administrator user.

Even if I set: `define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', '/srv/www/web/tmp/' );`

it still doesn't work, [this is how the administrative panel of my admin user of the web site is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbkfc.png)

Could you please tell me what parameters I need to set for the site to work. Thanks in advance.

I need to know how to solve this

Comment: on your screenshot I see default dashboard of user with role "subscriber", you should be either Administrator or Super Administrator to see full dashboard. It is definetely not problem of hosting provider restrictions.